# HC-08 Compatibility issues with iPhone

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to connect my IPhone to an HC-08 Bluetooth module on an Arduino. The HC-08 is showing up in the new device section of android devices but it does not show up on an IPhone's Bluetooth device adding page. Also although it shows up on Android it will not successfully pair. I have an IPhone 13 which uses Bluetooth v5 and the HC-08 uses Bluetooth v4. I think Bluetooth v5 should be backwards compatible so that should not be the issue.

Here are my questions:

1. Could the problem be that I need to write some Arduino initialization code? Currently I am not writing any code and just trying to connect to the device to my phone.
2. Is it common that these modules will stop working over time? I have had this for several years and never used it.
3. Is there another common reason that this will not show up in the Bluetooth menu of an IPhone such as a security setting?

Comment: Have you tried to use Bluefruit Connect on the iPhone to see if it can detect your bluetooth module?